# How do I convert the value from FormGroup to HTMLFormElement or string?

Tags: typescript, angular6, formgroups

I'm trying to convert the value from FormGroup to HTMLFormElement or string. I need it for the emailjs-com sendForm function that I'm trying to pass the value to in my onSubmit() function in the Typescript file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `return 'hello';` would convert a FormGroup value to a string. It's probably not what you want, but if you don't tell what the form group value is, and what the string should be, it's quite hard for us to help.

Comment: according to the docs the form passed in can be HTMLFormElement or query selector. I've tried passing in as follows: var contactFormQS = document.querySelector('#contactForm'); and emailjs.sendForm('my_service', 'my_template', contactFormQS, 'my_id') but I'm getting an error: ERROR in src/app/contact/contact.component.ts(59,53): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | HTMLFormElement'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'HTMLFormElement'.
    Property 'acceptCharset' is missing in type 'Element'.

Comment: ok got it to work but the emailjs is affecting other javascript npm packages. Is there anyway to prevent this behavior?

Comment: ok figured it out I had two e.preventdefault statements in different scripts and one affected the other